# Multiple categories at once from Sendgrid API request returns status 400 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, categories, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to receive the email statistics for multiple categories at once from Sendgrid API. I have @sendgrid/client installed and I'm using this peace of code:

```js
const client = require('@sendgrid/client')
 client.setDefaultRequest('qsStringifyOptions', {arrayFormat: 'repeat'});
 client.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

 const request = {}
 const queryParams = {
  'aggregated_by': 'day',
  'categories': ['cat1', 'cat2'],
  'start_date': '2021-08-01',
  'end_date': '2021-09-01',
  'limit': 5,
  'offset': 1
 };
 request.qs = queryParams;
 request.method = 'GET';
 request.url = '/v3/categories/stats';
 client
  .request(request)
  .then(([response, body]) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

taken from https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/packages/client/USAGE.md#get-categoriesstats.
When I execute it I receive Error Code 400 and "body: { errors: [Array] }". When I replace 'categories': ['cat1', 'cat2'], with 'categories': cat1', it works. It returns Code 200 and valid Object with stats in it. What am I missing? Is this some kind of syntax error. I don't have much experience with API's.

Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

After couple chat sessions with Sendgrid support here what is end situation. By using  following code

```js
   const client = require('@sendgrid/client')
client.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
client.setDefaultRequest('qsStringifyOptions', {arrayFormat: 'repeat'});

const request = {}
const queryParams = {
  'aggregated_by': 'day',
  'categories': 'dallas',
  'start_date': '2021-08-31',
  'end_date': '2021-09-01',
  'limit': 1,
  'offset': 1
};
request.method = 'GET';
request.url = '/v3/categories/stats?start_date=2021-09-01&categories=cat1&categories=cat2&limit=99&aggregated_by=week';
client
  .request(request)
  .then(([response]) => {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    console.log(response.body);
    
    }).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

I can retrieve stats for cat1 and cat2, but if you looking for campaigns containing both categories cat1 AND cat2, you can't do that with API.
Let say you have a multiple people working on multiple markets and you are looking for stats for specific person on specific market, best solution is when creating email blast to add multiple categories: 1) salesperson_name 2) market 3) market&salesperson_name and then pull stats for market&salesperson_name category.